# Alignment issue of html through CSS

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie of html and css whereas tyring to practice a couple of things of formulating but my efforts getting into futile.

Please find the code below, and images for your kind reference to get to know your opinion.

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
}

.picture {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.oliver {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50px;
}

.popular {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #666;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.follow-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background-color: #0f6fb0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  color: white;
  font: verdana;
}

.follow-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="picture" src="/Users/riyazmohamed/Desktop/HTML-CSS/Intro-to-html/channel-picture/cat.jpeg" alt="cat" />
  <p class="oliver">oliver</p>

  <p class="popular">the popular cat</p>
</div>
<div class="follow-div">
  <button class="follow-button">Follow</button>
</div>
```

[image: current output]

I want the content of "the papular of cat" to be under Oliver like under picture.

[image: desired output]

Please help me, thank you.

content need to be formulated under the olive, please help me to get it done per lateral picture given as sample.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the possible solutions using Flexbox. Just wrap the image in one div, p tags are already block-level elements but I have wrapped them also in divs. After that use the display: flex on the .container and that's it.

Here is the link [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mkozlica/pen/ExGbwZZ)

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
  <img class="picture" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAoHCBYVFRgUFRYYGRgaHBgZHBocHBgcHB4hHhUcHBwcGiMcLi4lIR4rIBwhJzgnKy8xNTU1HCQ7QDs0Py41NjEBDAwMEA8QHhISHzQrJSs2NDQ2NDQ2PTQ0NDQ2NDQ0NDQ2NDQ9NDQ0MTQxNDQ0NjQ0NjQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NP/AABEIAK4BIgMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAEAAgMBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQYDBAcCAf/EADoQAAEDAgMGBAQFAwMFAAAAAAEAAhEDIQQSMQUGQVFhcRMigZEyobHBQlJi0fAj4fEVJIIHFHKSsv/EABkBAQADAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBf/EAB8RAQEBAQADAQADAQAAAAAAAAABAhEDITESE0FRYf/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A7MiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiLC6u0ENLgCbASJQZkREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQfFqbSxPh0qlT8jHO9mkrbWhtynmw9ZvOm/wD+CovxM+xRdl7Wr/GKj7n4XAvnibCIHpKuOydtsreUw13IkX6jiqfsBzX0w1j4MfhBaO5JGqyYrDvaM2aIMy4tJnnLRb5LDOrPcdW/HL6+OiIqrsXeQGKdcgO0DpbDotNvrEXVoDwdCtpqVzazZ9e0XgPB4heiVZV9Recw5hefEExInug9r4SsdSs1oJJAAEmTw5qpbU274zjSouytHxOjXgGi4iex+arrUi2c21K43bEuy0rgGHO9NBxULj2uALgXSL9/bVbOEptYAAHQdS4Se3JaW8jJYCPzAA6EX+fZY3V52ujGJ3kXbDPJY0nUtaT6gLKsdFsNaOQA+SyLojlr6iIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICx1GS0g6EEe4hZEQco2U7wXPpZJex7mm0/iUlVqOcCWBw/UHAexWDevD/7x2UEEhrnC15Go56H2Wzh6YyZg/KeBF8p52/nVcc9dz/j0dWWTX+xrMwtR9y7LFyXEHOAdL+WeTh6rcq7Za0ZKbictiePPTuYPdYMdiiQ2k90yBLmgtnUkmJvwvMz7atF7KWUMpF0ODDUIvE3niIE3PJTysLXrFbRrU6gqQ40gyMo1zakn0+hUy/EVC1pLXBxykmbCxJ14Ry6KvVnvxLzQ0guDiI0jMJHUifVb2JFQtMv89J+Q2/NTDrT3HVTNWIs6yu245mdrmFzW2DgIkw0ls+ojnK0dm42tDrHJ4hIJ4NMEz0GZ3aFuDCuqU2UWkjxMzwRYtDcuUg8DBBnmSsGztouc8UfKHMgkjQwYAdxuIE90t6jjf/1RtSaLw6CJzQGixJaDPIAeq+twQZBbdrrtdNyec9f5otbG0WOfkqiHObIAMRcumO7gI9ys2ExXhMax7YDTlbN4+HvxJ4/hPIKPaZf8bIxTmiS7pLgAexP7rXc/x6lNg/E5oc2SRAvm9gpLH5PDzPMgAXIAInpr7la+7bGtriBIcxzw48Bpbr9k77k/1tLPxdSe4ugX1EXW4BERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREFR3vwIvWHxOaKcHSA4n55vkoXCYXwWZGtPmbOV14PJswSD0Ktu2iCWtOgvcSJ0AUU1hY+NBxNrzrBlc+pP1a6M6tzI06eynPZmcSCCSJnMOXb119Ft4JjWsLHHOb+Y5ZHKYVd303mc3/b0HGmGtL6tUtuxgI+Dm8kwFQt49qUqNdv8A22Lr1mkNc6p4jpDpNo+F1oMRaYSdvxFvPVdF3UpCm+u9582d3AjhA7g/2XrEVGubUOYjO8yNOGUEctJWpujVdiqTiSM4gOcLZgWy1/SRbuCtt9DL5XA6n+BZe7Gsufsbmz64FRjpgAPAE6h2Uu9i36rxiMIw45lRkAOaS+NIAtPIyfmVr0cKXvbHCfbr1UXvrjzhmhjHZHFpe94gua2coDZ/E42B/SVPuRF59W3aeHbVePPkBjTX+cVjxeyTlhrr/hMXAsdD217rku6+0cO/xn18XXwz2AOpkVHuLjcmQ6Q64Hli8rpW6W8rqrTRxBaajYOdohr2uAc1w4CQdFpfX1nL34+3ePCqOJIcfNYk2JEDRoA0J116qwbs0W5ZvmZmbJ1GYgnpwGixMoBziRccefMfDeJW3sow4uB+KMw6pmT9SmtX88TiIi6GAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiCm7fxYz/ABBrWnzGYjj9lr7MxTKmas4AyfLJmw0gNMdbhRO9ez31MT4Xmy/GS1wBg8I46LBUYWZWMgECMrjwnUydVybvK6cTsau/uzS9zq4tRq0vCc6DFJ7Xh7HVIHlYTYu4SuYjd7EZ8nhOnnbLHPN8OXrK7RhNpPYS0m5tGovzHEe+nFSuAxTB5mUaYjiGNBJ6ZRqk1Z8V1iqvuBSdhqz2vY4M8KmxriIzObJLo1DTmMSNBOhCtOJexziTHTjx/nsoja4fJrfCHOmeMf3XrZeNpxmqPgjUEfVZfrXfy2njkz1O4YMY6RB48J0XNt9qFTEV65ykU3sYGv1a0sJcM8Xa1xcRJsrZtLHMJ/pvm9yJGo49Oq2NmsdScytZwiCRHHWQOCfrX64a8cueuG0thVy7Lky8S9xAaB+Yu0jtK65uNsw0mvr1GkMcGU6YeC0llNmUPINwHGSOiseNxga7MWMbBsQ0T7xqoSrin1XE5jA/FMyJnjbhwWt3b9ZZxW5vDi20cldjgAHCb2cCYI48/lotnZWMHitIeHB4kQb8DeTpCjK2FdUAY6XseL2Av6rzu5svwcUGBgyuu18yRHAi8HqOiYvVtTkdLX1EXW5RERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREFX29Qayp4zuWth+8/JVLa21cOYcXNJ6HT2/wug7d2azEUix+ms3+y5idlsY+7GkzYgEAdRqVzeWcv/HT4b2Mmz8K6q/MxsMDbPe7NOmgBgDup+hUefLTY2pBAOV0Bo4FxuNBN1r4LC5ctQwGcJtm7c/SfRTGPrhrADncLEMpyHE9T1VJPXV9X29swjMQ0txDMs+WzxeRfKWG0GRbkqDvTu8/AONZlR9Sg4EAOuWOny5iNQbjNrOqumDIZ5/BYw3hpILgTe8WmSefdQ29u2CKT87rO8rW9YMGFpnObOWKzWs6ll+NPdXdU4knEYipUZScQWUZyZmhti+LgEyYBuCJ5K4vp+GDTo0i8WEB7BAJA4mYi/MxzUHsLbJfTa9pBBEZeAItHQfspGmcxzsYwnUhpyuMAiATabk3jRRrMnOQ/WtW23608WzOPDc17HHRrmuJsYJaSIi3UXUezDCl561FzzNg0wOpywACrVRe4tAPna2BDxFRvcmzwecjTitHGUYdJAZOhA1HT+yprP9pzr+mjhtv0SQCQ0fqLQfbUKx7Gw7HP8RsdxPHv9lVsVs9tU5Syeun3lXbYWCbSpNa2dONyreKW1Xy8k9JNERdTmEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQYMS6Gm8WVLx9Wmx05Q93Mxlae34j3EdFL7Z2h5g38I10En1VQxWNAebySTz9LrDyabePLDjnVHv8QOl3Akkgdp/spbY+OeGDxIDnEtYeB/M/sP3UXQwznua0GJgduZ/ZZsVii57ixsNYMjCeU5c3qA73WWfV63vucTlfDyHBgALpuL+/wAwoR+7wLTmlx4k34/usD8TWaZDsrbmTqXF7iBHQR7qZ2ftiwa8ZuuhK1lzWfNR4wW7rWgESwzNjY9D06KabgmNAzECDqel5+6i8ftl5afCaBbjrxUc7EOcG5ySXeYidOEfX5KLqImbU/jNo5mkUyC5sh0zFviHcfS/Q6FBzhJJzsJux1wD05HqNR6x8ofmbqQx4P6hafW6ymq1rW1HQxptfQE/hP6TqOSrfftb1JyN+nQAaXsBP6dT6REhTOy60jLyuFWX4gktyE5QZkEWPIx/D7qW2bjgXw74vzDQ+nP6q+LJWepbFgREW7EREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREHxeKzoaT0XtRe2se2m2C4BxuAot5Opk7eIDa7C6ftwVI2lLXe8SYI9b/RW3F4xgZncT5vwxP0uoOpSbXMNaCJ1mYXJr26s+mphqr2U3vaTncwhmhAk5JbHuf+BWPA1ntpnO8FznkTERlaIA7SvW1RkMzlDW3HIubI01IaGt/4BVuntElkTpVvx+Jkif8A0Kp228jScn1c6rxeLknMPUCO1oXh9bKYOvL+cFgweJ8o0kCD9fv8lCbZxT8zSy9wY53n2spl9p4nK2Ie2AAJM2M6ZR+49l9wuGcAXjU6g31tblr/ACFqU68Bj32LRf8A5CT9x6BbWL2i1gyW8zss8vMIKrfZ8TDcTDGFpvBju17jB9vmlSsM2R4ljtQdIcMzXN6g6+qg6eJLAwRMDMes1HrNiqrntZ+QgzaSIdMgjUAOA7BWmlLlIYLEZXuAuLtOgJAMQQeIUzgMweLyLEECJH84d1DU6bAQWidA70EA/wA5Kw4PEtIF76gTB6iPsr4qm4tVI+UTyWRY6J8o7BZF1uUREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERB8WhjtqU6XxuAJ0Gv0XjbmOFGi95MQD/AIHVUnAY84horlpAiBmjl5o7G0zwKw8vlufUa+Px/r3Vgrb1U8xa1wMR8N9ecaLRpb3+YSLTEyYF4kyAIUVXex72lrQ+A+XSAB5hY8eE+y0WV6DqhYMgc0uBAIMRa44duh6Lmu9X37bzGF/pbcabGx5wY+SisaHOLg9s5hYi/a6qO1N4jgtGNeCdC4N/DoC6xMNMAXVh2ftZtegyvS+B4mI0OjmwNDKtrWtZlqJnObyIZ9EszMf8NzBkyeHy4/wZNnnKII8pIboLTYwBbSf5ZZdqV6b2EuDgRraD3H7qOwWOIb8JIh7gBEkkZW25W+Y4Kub1azjT21QdVnLIzGTHUnisWx9iNaHh0EEAi0mWEkfLMt7xQbhxBFja2twOboBvzWvisW9hljT5Yka3HbgLD/KjnGnetuq1jQWjl7nSFEuqsc/haw9ot7j3Xqq8uc4TADSRyyyRHpp6LUZhDmJY2wcB5uED5CIVP7WTFbDh4ItYtI9yI91hrbPzAB2v7CP52WLAOcCZOfzN0IiSfsQpI4qXhuhLvL0hzvtCnnVe8a9SGFgkgta1hkc2SZ4amVK4drQwT+Yz0zNAHzaoLFVA5865iDrYaEHqDp6LcOMa6mTTcPiAE8SG/DJtF+PRWk9ovxtU8QGuM5RwkHW9j6GCtrYlV76hOV0g8ffhbXl9lWqYc92UNgkyddSbz10+avmCp+GySQBlJcdOHmN/X3VpVNROnbDWNAdrHCTEc1E47evI7KBJGt7CdBaTKpuH3yGJe6lTY0M8wa6W5iAQJyjzAEmxOq2sdUosILy2TPENBJE6nifup1vffzVc4z9WqhvYyA5xABIF9Ln82imsHtujUMNe2e/05qhtyBzHlgDIccwcIHkJzGe0fPtuV6kN8RgLslxFyRF/kNOiZ82oa8Wa6GEVb3P2yMTTJHBzhB1sbH1F1ZF2Z1+p1y6nLx9REVkCIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiIKp/1DwBrYOo0SDEgiZBBkEQqvsFgZg6TdTkgnrx/aOC6dXpBzSHCQeCgMZuuwty0jkF/KSXNuZtNxdc/lxb8bePcz9ULZjMj64aXNDocRa5BIJnWI4LUbs4U8bTqNuKrXB4mQHNLSHCOJAv37rf29sDEYRza5fTex/wDTyjMHS4SHExBuB9bqw092X4hjCagYWZSHtu8cwJEQRAvyVJjXxe6n1XNvYOnUJY4/hDo+KS1wjXTylysGxNhObhMPSpN8rWgvOYC5bePUkqYw25uHbUbVeX1HtBHncMpnWWtAB9VY2sAAAAAGgFgOy0x4uTlU15ffYqT9hVoPkaTwGZv3UPit0sRDixrcxaG3cLXbOtjoV0hFb+HKs8uo5O3c/Gl5e+m2dGw9sATf1iTPPLyvtt3VxcA+G0HiA9sRMDje3zXTUT+HKf5dOZVd1MVdrabYOUA52iBYO04eUHuVpVtzMa4nytAmwztjSCT7BdaRRfBmpnn1HJKe5+Oa3KykwWF8zefC/Ikeqy4jdTHSXspMLplsvZ+KC4dtV1ZfUnhzEXzarhtXcTabn5sjMsgj+o0ZfKAQI4fsCpTD7i4wNDXMZdz3OIeI8wboO4PuuuorXxZpPLqKHs7dOoy7mjNxvr111Uv/AKdUaIcJZlc11xMGFZUUTw5k4i+XVrimx9jU8O/KLEvIj9LXPLb9y32WXeTZ4r18NSNmS57iCZhrYDb85v2XSNp7q4es4PLSx4JIcxxbc6kj4T6hQ1TdQ0Xur+KanlgZwAWiZOXKIM6SVnfHZr9NJ5JZxV9psmgWFxyuc1pAykRIJA5WgevBTGygPDykWj1FlDt2TiMViDRpvpt8Muc4uzHMDYAADWCb8Os2u2yt1ywf1nB3/iXCbRBNjEWss/49Xi38kiv/APSfZxpis8kuzuMHoCYA4Rx7krpK1cDgKdFoZTaGtHC5+q2l1Ylk9ufV7X1ERXVEREBERAREQf/Z" alt="cat" />
  </div>
<div>
  <p class="oliver">oliver</p>
  </div>
  <div>
  <p class="popular">the popular cat</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="follow-div">
  <button class="follow-button">Follow</button>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.picture {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.oliver {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50px;
}

.popular {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #666;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.follow-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background-color: #0f6fb0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  color: white;
  font: verdana;
}

.follow-div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/y23360db5

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .image {
            width: 100px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
            height: auto;
            margin-right: 10px; /* Add spacing between the image and text */
        }

        .text {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://clipart.info/images/ccovers/1522855947cartoon-cat-png-clip-art.png" alt="Oliver the cat" class="image">
        <div>
            <span class="text">Oliver</span><br>
            The popular cat
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]